# How to plot error bars on a graph?

Tags: r, data-visualization, standard-deviation, scatterplot

How to plot error bars on a graph in R?
Assume I have 3 columns in a table: x, y, errors of measured y.
What kind of plot should I use?

Comment: have you seen this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032777/scatter-plot-with-error-bars

Comment: You might be better on an R site. Note that there at least three competing graphical systems in R and you would get better answers if you specify which of them you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the right place to ask but there you go.

```
n = sqrt(nrow(iris3))
alpha = 0.05
X = iris3

mus = apply(X, 2, mean)
sem = qnorm(1-alpha/2) * apply(X, 2, sd) / n

# Plot bars:
library(gplots)
hb <- barplot2(mus, main="Mean Plot\nSignificance bars", ylab="Means", xlab="Groups", col=c("lightblue"), names.arg = names(mus), cex.names=0.8, ylim=c(0, max(mus)+max(sem) ))

# Plot the vertical lines of the error bars:
segments(hb, mus-sem, hb, mus+sem, lwd=2)

# Plot the horizontal bounds for the error bars:
segments(hb-0.1, mus+sem, hb+0.1, mus+sem, lwd=3)   # The upper bar
segments(hb-0.1, mus-sem, hb+0.1, mus-sem, lwd=3)   # The lower bar
```